# Binding data to a simple range slider

Tags: html, rangeslider

I need to bind an input field to a slider

```
<input id="testScore" type="text" min="0" max="100" name="testScore" value="{{testForm.testScore}}" ng-model="testForm.testScore" ng-pattern="onlyNumbers"><span id="unit">%</span>
<input class="progress-slider" type="range" min="0" max="100" ng-model="testForm.testScore">
<div class="inner" ng-style="{ width: selectedRange + '%' || '0%' }"></div>
```

So when I give text type as "number" I can type the input which changes the slider position, I can even get the range, but when i try to move the slider, the input field value is not shown. Like there is only one way binding.

But when I give type as "text" it is binding two ways, entering value inside the input moves the slider as well as moving the slider changes the input value, but I cannot get it to have  a range from 0-100 because it is a text type input.

Is there a way I can solve it with getting two way binding and to have the min and max range defined.